# How to write Moses decoder translations into a file?

Tags: moses

I'm trying to test the Moses decoder. I have huge amounts of data and I need to record their translations into a file. I mean giving all the data to Moses and recording the translations into a file. Is there anyone who can help me? I have used this link: http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.Baseline and now I can just give a sentence to it inorder to translate.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show your current code? How is the data currently recorded?

Comment: Actually I have tested it by these guides: http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.Baseline. And now I am looking for the right place to write a code for recording translations. Thanks!